# Fast Classic ASP Encryption

Tags: asp.net, asp-classic, com+

I have this function (COM+) object that does all the encryption, but when it get's too many requests at once, it error's out and crashes. I get errors like 'Page On End Error' and stuff like that always, so I'm wondering, what's the fastest Encryption (strong) tool out there for Encryption in Classic ASP?

I'm pretty sure ASP.NET has a built-in encryption function, but wondering if this can be accessed via Classic ASP, and if it will be stable without returning errors when over-?

The encyption strength needs to be 128-256 bit AES or Triple-Des.

Comment: Are you sure the component is thread-safe? How many requests is too many? What would be the impact of serialising access to it from ASP pages by using an Application.Lock?  How much data is being encrypted at once?

Comment: Have you ever tried to use **[Capicom](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa375732(v=VS.85).aspx)**?

Answer (score 2):

For string manipulation I have found JavaScript to work better, the great thing about ASP is you can use multiple languages.

For AES encryption you can use [ecmaScrypt](http://www.josh-davis.org/ecmaScrypt), instead of saving the file as .js, save it as .asp and add `<script language="JScript" runat="server">` at the top of the file and `</script>` at the end, you now have a server side AES library, which you can include in any ASP file and call it normally.

I.E. `Encrypt("somestring", "your key here")`